# Eclipse - Auto create setters returning the class and auto completion for methods

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, setter

I read this [tips](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html) but couldn't find out...

How can I:

- Create setters which return the class, instead of `void`?
- Make Eclipse auto add a comment - which is the name of the method, after the last curly bracket mark of the method? For example:

  ```
  public void test() {
  }// test()
  ```

**Edited**

Thanks, I make an example of the first question:

```
public class A {

    public A setB(...) {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

As I want this is auto for quick fix <kbd>Ctrl-1</kbd> -> *Create setter and getter*... I mean can I have Eclipse to:

- auto set `public A` for setters, instead of `void`?
- then append `return this;` at the end of setters?

I'm sorry my first question is `getters`. I fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean by  "return the class" ? Also I've found a link which may help you for adding auto-comment for your eclipse(actually I strongly recommend you to write the comments on your own) : http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @aphex, Thanks. I just need that auto completion since I type it for most of methods...

Answer (score 0):

To return the class from one of its methods, use "return this;" and change the return type from void to the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to have a constructor and if you have at least one property, you can get accessors and mutators as a shortcut. You can follow this way from the menu(For Eclipse):

```
Source -> Generate getters and setters
```

Now, you can add add getters and setters automatically(if you have a constructor and if you have variables for initializing)

EDIT : **I think there is no way to get these methods by using keyboard**

EDIT 2: **I've looked up for the hotkey of Source menu. You can follow Alt + Shift + S followed by R, but It seems an unproper way for this**

Comment: Thanks, I know how to add setters/ getters automatically by Eclipse. I just wish if I can have Eclipse adds setters which return the instance of class?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Ctrl-1` while the cursor stands at the fields/ variables.

Comment: @haibison I think you mean "getters" instead of "setters" . Actually Eclipse has no such feature for adding personal methods. But hopefully there would be a plugin to fulfill it.

Comment: I would be happy if I could help you somehow. As you stated in your question, you want a method named as "setBlabla" but it will return something. I think if you want to set some property, either you have a constructor for instantiating your object, or you have a setter method which should not return anything, it should be void.

Comment: If I have a bean which has multi fields, for example I can call it as: `a.setB().setC().setD()...`. As like as a string buffer: `s.append("a").append("b")`... Anyway this is just the feature of a program. I can do it by hand. Honestly, thank you so much for trying to help me.